# How can i implement an intro slider before the splash screen first time?

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="demo.com.xapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".IntroActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Intro sliders Activity

```
public class IntroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager screenPager;
    IntroViewPagerAdapter introViewPagerAdapter ;
    TabLayout tabIndicator;
    Button btnNext;
    int position = 0 ;
    Button btnGetStarted;
    Animation btnAnim ;
    TextView tvSkip;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // make the activity on full screen

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        // when this activity is about to be launch we need to check if its openened before or not

        if (restorePrefData()) {

            Intent mainActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SplashActivity.class );
            startActivity(mainActivity);
            finish();


        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

        // hide the action bar

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        // ini views
        btnNext = findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
        btnGetStarted = findViewById(R.id.btn_get_started);
        tabIndicator = findViewById(R.id.tab_indicator);
        btnAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.button_animation);
        tvSkip = findViewById(R.id.tv_skip);

        // fill list screen

        final List<ScreenItem> mList = new ArrayList<>();
        mList.add(new ScreenItem("Fresh Food","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua, consectetur  consectetur adipiscing elit",R.drawable.img1));
        mList.add(new ScreenItem("Fast Delivery","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua, consectetur  consectetur adipiscing elit",R.drawable.img2));
        mList.add(new ScreenItem("Easy Payment","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua, consectetur  consectetur adipiscing elit",R.drawable.img3));

        // setup viewpager
        screenPager =findViewById(R.id.screen_viewpager);
        introViewPagerAdapter = new IntroViewPagerAdapter(this,mList);
        screenPager.setAdapter(introViewPagerAdapter);

        // setup tablayout with viewpager

        tabIndicator.setupWithViewPager(screenPager);

        // next button click Listner

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                position = screenPager.getCurrentItem();
                if (position < mList.size()) {

                    position++;
                    screenPager.setCurrentItem(position);


                }

                if (position == mList.size()-1) { // when we rech to the last screen

                    // TODO : show the GETSTARTED Button and hide the indicator and the next button

                    loaddLastScreen();


                }



            }
        });

        // tablayout add change listener


        tabIndicator.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.BaseOnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                if (tab.getPosition() == mList.size()-1) {

                    loaddLastScreen();

                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });



        // Get Started button click listener

        btnGetStarted.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                //open main activity

                Intent mainActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SplashActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainActivity);
                // also we need to save a boolean value to storage so next time when the user run the app
                // we could know that he is already checked the intro screen activity
                // i'm going to use shared preferences to that process
                savePrefsData();
                finish();



            }
        });

        // skip button click listener

        tvSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                screenPager.setCurrentItem(mList.size());
            }
        });



    }

    private boolean restorePrefData() {


        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean isIntroActivityOpnendBefore = pref.getBoolean("isIntroOpnend",false);
        return  isIntroActivityOpnendBefore;



    }

    private void savePrefsData() {

        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isIntroOpnend",true);
        editor.commit();


    }

    // show the GETSTARTED Button and hide the indicator and the next button
    private void loaddLastScreen() {

        btnNext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btnGetStarted.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvSkip.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tabIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        // TODO : ADD an animation the getstarted button
        // setup animation
        btnGetStarted.setAnimation(btnAnim);



    }
}
```

IntroViewPagerAdapter activity-

```
public class IntroViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    List<ScreenItem> mListScreen;

    public IntroViewPagerAdapter(Context mContext, List<ScreenItem> mListScreen) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mListScreen = mListScreen;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layoutScreen = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_screen,null);

        ImageView imgSlide = layoutScreen.findViewById(R.id.intro_img);
        TextView title = layoutScreen.findViewById(R.id.intro_title);
        TextView description = layoutScreen.findViewById(R.id.intro_description);

        title.setText(mListScreen.get(position).getTitle());
        description.setText(mListScreen.get(position).getDescription());
        imgSlide.setImageResource(mListScreen.get(position).getScreenImg());

        container.addView(layoutScreen);

        return layoutScreen;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mListScreen.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object o) {
        return view == o;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }
}
```

Screen Item Activity-

```
public class ScreenItem {
    String Title, Description;
    int ScreenImg;

    public ScreenItem(String title, String description, int screenImg) {
        Title = title;
        Description = description;
        ScreenImg = screenImg;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        Title = title;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }

    public void setScreenImg(int screenImg) {
        ScreenImg = screenImg;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public int getScreenImg() {
        return ScreenImg;
    }
}
```

Splash Screen Activity-

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public void onAttachedToWindow() {
            super.onAttachedToWindow();
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
        }
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        Thread splashTread;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
            StartAnimations();
        }
        private void StartAnimations() {
            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
            anim.reset();
            LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_lay);
            l.clearAnimation();
            l.startAnimation(anim);

            anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
            anim.reset();
            TextView iv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.splash);
            iv.clearAnimation();
            iv.startAnimation(anim);

            splashTread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        int waited = 0;
                        // Splash screen pause time
                        while (waited < 6000) {
                            sleep(100);
                            waited += 100;
                        }
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                                MainActivity.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        SplashActivity.this.finish();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // do nothing
                    } finally {
                        SplashActivity.this.finish();
                    }

                }
            };
            splashTread.start();

        }

    }
```

*how can we show Intro sliders before the splash screen on the first time when the app installed. Second time only splash screen shows not the intro sliders. I am new to android please help me to solve this problem.*

Answer (score 2):

You can save some value using sharedPreference, every time that the user will enter to your app check for the value of the saved sharedPreference to see if this is the first time or not. 

**First create a method to return the proper boolean value if this is the first time of the user or not:**

```
 //check if this is the user first time in the app and if it not - do not show tutorial
public static Boolean checkPref(Context context ,String prefKey){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean firstStart = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(prefKey,true);
    //if this is the users first time return true
    if(firstStart){
        return  true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Now create a method to change your sharedPreference for the time the user will first login to your app**

```
  public static void changePrefs(Context context,String key){
    //this part will change the first time loging boolean fron true to false(this will make sure that the user wont see the tutorial again )
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key,false);
    editor.apply();
}
```

**When the user will enter your app check if this is his first time:**

```
 if(checkPref(Context,"yourkey")){
        //the user is logged in for the first time
        callFirstTimeMethod();
    }
```

**And after the user was logged in for the first time you need to change your sharedPreference value so you will know that he is not a first timer(for his future logins)**

```
private void callFirstTimeMethod() {
    //your code goes here for the first time

    changePrefs(Context,"yourkey");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

WelcomeActivity.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import com.example.pagatodo.Common.PrefManager;
import com.example.pagatodo.R;
import com.example.pagatodo.SplashScreenActivity;

public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
    private LinearLayout dotsLayout;
    private TextView[] dots;
    private int[] layouts;
    private Button btnSkip, btnNext;
    private PrefManager prefManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Checking for first time launch - before calling setContentView()
        prefManager = new PrefManager(this);
        if (!prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
            launchHomeScreen();
            finish();
        }

        // Making notification bar transparent
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);
        btnSkip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);

        layouts = new int[]{
                R.layout.welcome_slide1,
                R.layout.welcome_slide2,
//                R.layout.welcome_slide3,
                R.layout.welcome_slide4};

        // adding bottom dots
        addBottomDots(0);

        // making notification bar transparent
        changeStatusBarColor();

        myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

        btnSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                launchHomeScreen();
            }
        });

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // checking for last page
                // if last page home screen will be launched
                int current = getItem(+1);
                if (current < layouts.length) {
                    // move to next screen
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
                } else {
                    launchHomeScreen();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {
        dots = new TextView[layouts.length];

        int[] colorsActive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_active);
        int[] colorsInactive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_inactive);

        dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i] = new TextView(this);
            dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
            dots[i].setTextSize(35);
            dots[i].setTextColor(colorsInactive[currentPage]);
            dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
        }

        if (dots.length > 0)
            dots[currentPage].setTextColor(colorsActive[currentPage]);
    }

    private int getItem(int i) {
        return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
    }

    private void launchHomeScreen() {
        prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
        startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, SplashScreenActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    //  viewpager change listener
    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            addBottomDots(position);

            // changing the next button text 'NEXT' / 'GOT IT'
            if (position == layouts.length - 1) {
                // last page. make button text to GOT IT
                btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.start));
                btnSkip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                // still pages are left
                btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.next));
                btnSkip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }
    };

    /**
     * Making notification bar transparent
     */
    private void changeStatusBarColor() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }

    /**
     * View pager adapter
     */
    public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
            container.addView(view);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return layouts.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
            return view == obj;
        }


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            View view = (View) object;
            container.removeView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_welcome.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_welcome">


    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dots_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dots_margin_bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:alpha=".5"
        android:layout_above="@id/layoutDots"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_skip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/skip"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```